Mesh keeps unwrapping as a page of dots in the UV editor
I am trying to bake the textures on the "head piece" of this model so that I can get it into Unity. But every time I smart unwrap my object, the UV editor presents the mesh as a bunch of dots, and I think it's affecting the quality of the image textures; every time I plug my color texture back it, it looks very pixelated.
Before applying image textures:

After applying "baked" displacement:

After applying other image textures:

Any help is appreciated.
Here is the file.

Hello it's not clear what you are trying to do, but if the UV is divided into a lot of small faces it's because all the edges of your mesh are marked as seams

Would that hamper the quality of my bake? If so, how should I fix it?

No it works with this unwrap but you could remove the seams and unwrap with the Smart UV Project option. Also, if you want a narrow margin you can set it in the Operator Box (panel on the bottom left of your 3D window once you've unwrapped)

I see. I just have that many faces. Is there any way I can make my bake less pixelated (see third image)?

Yes, don't use the UV output of the Texture Coordinate for example   ;)  actually it's not clear what you're trying to do, what kind of material are you trying to achieve and are you trying to bake the diffuse?
